# Regex to match section and data

Tags: c#, regex

i've got a huge file with different sections (16), i've pasted a small portion below. I'm trying to split the sections, but can't seem to group the "data"

My Regex-patterb to split the sections is (<strike>although this only seems to capture the first Section part only</strike> i'm getting al sections now, just no data)

```
(?<Section>^Section.*$)
```

When i try to add the regex part for the data it only matches the section (according to [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e((%3f%3a%5eSection.*%24)%0d%0a(%3f%3CData%3E%5b+%5d*))&i=Section+1+Who+-+All+accounts%3a+1+record+per+account%0d%0a++++Account+number%2cGroup+name%2cSubgroup+name%2cCustomer+name%2cAccount+ref1%2cAccount+ref2%2cInvoice+name%2cInvoice+number%2cInvoice+date%2cRecurring+amount%2cOcc%2cCommercial+Credits%2cDiscounts%2cTotal+excl.+VAT%2cVAT%2cTotal+incl.+VAT%2cCurrency%0d%0a++++%2200001%22%2c%22Unfiled+-+Niet+toegekend+-+Non+attribu%C3%A9%22%2c%22%22%2c%22Reference1%22%2c%22gemeentesecretariaat%22%2c%2210408%22%2c%22Reference11%22%2c%22160600501092%22%2c%2211%2fFEB%2f2016%22%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c%22EUR%22%2c%0d%0a++++%2200002%22%2c%22Unfiled+-+Niet+toegekend+-+Non+attribu%C3%A9%22%2c%22%22%2c%22Reference2%22%2c%22receptieve+ruimten%22%2c%2276005%22%2c%22Reference21%22%2c%22160600433432%22%2c%2211%2fFEB%2f2016%22%2c0.0%2c-5.8393%2c0.0%2c4.4985%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c0.0%2c%22EUR%22%2c%0d%0a++++%0d%0aSection+14+Who+-+All+subscribers+-+Data+Volume%3a+1+record+per+Data+session%0d%0a++++GSM+number%2cGroup+name%2cSubgroup+name%2cName+GSM+number%2cUser+ref1%2cUser+Ref2%2cCall+date%2cCall+time%2cTotal+volume+(MB)%2cService%2cZone%2fCountry%2fOperator%2cTariff%2cType%2cSupplementary+services%2cUsage+amount%2cCurrency%2cAccount+number%0d%0a++++%220XXX%2fXXXXXX%22%2c%22Departement+1%22%2c%22Unfiled+-+Niet+toegekend+-+Non+attribu%C3%A9%22%2c%22Familyname%22%2c%223000000%22%2c%2214%22%2c%2217%2fJAN%2f2016%22%2c%2214%3a42%3a12%22%2c%220.1470%22%2c%22Mobile+Internet%22%2c%22%22%2c%22Daluur%22%2c%22GPRS+nationaal%22%2c%22%22%2c0.0%2c%22EUR%22%2c%2225000000%22%2c%0d%0a++++%220XXX%2fXXXXXX%22%2c%22Departement+1%22%2c%22Unfiled+-+Niet+toegekend+-+Non+attribu%C3%A9%22%2c%22Familyname%22%2c%223000000%22%2c%2214%22%2c%2231%2fJAN%2f2016%22%2c%2219%3a55%3a08%22%2c%220.3110%22%2c%22Mobile+Internet%22%2c%22%22%2c%22Daluur%22%2c%22GPRS+nationaal%22%2c%22%22%2c0.0%2c%22EUR%22%2c%2225000000%22%2c&o=xm))

```
^((?<Section>^Section.*$)
(?<Data>[ ]*))
```

The file i'm trying to split is the following

```
Section 1 Who - All accounts: 1 record per account
Account number,Group name,Subgroup name,Customer name,Account ref1,Account ref2,Invoice name,Invoice number,Invoice date,Recurring amount,Occ,Commercial Credits,Discounts,Total excl. VAT,VAT,Total incl. VAT,Currency
"00001","Unfiled - Niet toegekend - Non attribué","","Reference1","gemeentesecretariaat","10408","Reference11","160600501092","11/FEB/2016",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,"EUR",
"00002","Unfiled - Niet toegekend - Non attribué","","Reference2","receptieve ruimten","76005","Reference21","160600433432","11/FEB/2016",0.0,-5.8393,0.0,4.4985,0.0,0.0,0.0,"EUR",

Section 14 Who - All subscribers - Data Volume: 1 record per Data session
GSM number,Group name,Subgroup name,Name GSM number,User ref1,User Ref2,Call date,Call time,Total volume (MB),Service,Zone/Country/Operator,Tariff,Type,Supplementary services,Usage amount,Currency,Account number
"0XXX/XXXXXX","Departement 1","Unfiled - Niet toegekend - Non attribué","Familyname","3000000","14","17/JAN/2016","14:42:12","0.1470","Mobile Internet","","Daluur","GPRS nationaal","",0.0,"EUR","25000000",
"0XXX/XXXXXX","Departement 1","Unfiled - Niet toegekend - Non attribué","Familyname","3000000","14","31/JAN/2016","19:55:08","0.3110","Mobile Internet","","Daluur","GPRS nationaal","",0.0,"EUR","25000000",
```

So the goal is to have every "Section" as a Section-group and all the data in it as a Data-group.  In order to parse each section seperatly i need to get it to split first, as parsing the whole file wouldn't be possible anyway without splitting it first :)

The code i'm using for splitting the file is the following:

```
public static void ReadFromSectionedCsv(this DataSet dataset, string filepath)
    {
        const string PATTERN = @"
 ^((?<Section>^Section.*$)
 (?<Data>[ ]*))";
        dataset.Clear();
        using (Stream filestream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string fileContetnt;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filestream, encoding))
            {
                fileContetnt = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var match = Regex.Matches(fileContetnt, PATTERN,
                RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (Match m in match)
            {
                var sectionmatch = m.Groups["Section"];
                var datamatch = m.Groups["Data"];

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.Write(datamatch.Value);
                    writer.Flush();
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    dataset.Tables.Add(sectionmatch.Value).ReadFromCsv(stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advanced for any help!

Comment: Are you using `RegexOptions.Multiline`?

Comment: yes, i'm using that and RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace

Comment: For both expressions?  Might be helpful to post your code.

Comment: @CodingGorilla i've added the code in my initial question

Comment: So the first problem is that `.*` + `RegexOptions.Multiline` means: "Give me everything else in the file" (or string).  You have to delimit it with something else to break up the sections, are you open to doing this in other ways rather than using a regex?

Comment: I was hoping to do this with regex as i thought it was possible, i'm already getting each section seperatly, so that part is working, it's just getting the "data" part, what i was hoping would work with a more advanced regex then i'm using, or am i wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106260/discussion-between-codinggorilla-and-yoeri-rousseaux).

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead expression (`(?=^Section|\Z)`) to match the next `Section` or end of string, and also use ungreedy `Data` consumption (`(.|\n)*?`).

```
(?<MySection>^Section(.)+)(?<MyData>(.|\n)*?)(?=^Section|\Z)
```

Comment: Should work, just check the [regexstorm](http://goo.gl/tAjSwJ). There are 2 matches. And sorry the ungreedy match should be inside the `MyData` group. See my updated regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two options.

> If your file is huge:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^.*(?=(\r?\n)\1)|(?<=(\r?\n)).*",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);

Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(text);
while (matchResults.Success) {
    var section = matchResults.Value
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

Just keep iterating over matches and process accordingly.

> If it's reasonable.

```
string[] splitArray = null;
try {
    splitArray = Regex.Split(url, @"^\s*$", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

This will split sections into array.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this one](https://regex101.com/r/tP7tD6/3):

```
(Section(?:.|\n)*?(?=Section|$))+
```